# OrderByDescending does not change order of items in the list

Tags: c#

The following return folders in order

```
03-march 
05-may
```

How can I mofify the following code to get the order in inverse

```
05-may 
03-march
```

Code:

```
private void loadGrid()
{
    List<FileArchive> fiList = new List<FileArchive>();

    String path = Request.QueryString["Path"];
    DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(path);

    FileInfo[] files = info.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(m => m.CreationTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd")).ToArray();
    foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
    {
        FileArchive FA = new FileArchive();
        FA.Name = fi.Name;
        FA.FullName = fi.FullName;

        FA.CreationDate = fi.CreationTime;
        FA.RegroupingField =fi.CreationTime.ToString("MM") + "-" + 
        fi.CreationTime.ToString("MMMM") + " | " + fi.CreationTime.Year;

        fiList.Add(FA);
        fiList.OrderByDescending(m => m.CreationDate.ToString("MM"));      
    }
```

Comment: Don't order on the string representation of the date; order on the actual date value.

Comment: just use `Enumerable.Reverse`

Comment: @Servy That's a good advice in general, but why would it help here?

Comment: @svick The string representation of the date may not have the same ordering as the actual date value.

Comment: Are you sure the `CreationTime` matches the directory (or is it a file?) name?

Comment: user3868796, I've update title of your post to match your problem - feel free to revert/improve.

Comment: Side note: you may also want to check out questions about "natural sort" which is very close to what you trying to achieve (or may even plan to do in future).

Comment: @Servy I don't see how. I think that `ToString("yyyyMMdd")` should always return a string that orders correctly. At least it does for all cultures that are installed on my computer (the only difference is that some cultures don't use Gregorian calendar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `OrderByDescending` does not order a list in place.  You need to store and enumerate the return value to use the sorted list.

I would move this line:

```
fiList.OrderByDescending(m => m.CreationDate.ToString("MM"));
```

Out of the for loop (you only need to sort once when you are done), and change it like this:

```
var sortedList = fiList.OrderByDescending(m => m.CreationDate.ToString("MM"));
```

Additionally, it would be more efficent and less error prone to sort on an actual date instead of the string representation of the month.  To do this, remove the `ToString` call and leave the date.

```
var sortedList = fiList.OrderByDescending(m => m.CreationDate);
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534855(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: +1. Consider removing `ToString` call in favor of [DateTime.Month](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.month%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or even just `m=>m.CreationDate`.

Comment: I agree that would be an improvement, but I didn't want to change the OP implementation more than required.

Comment: @user3868796 when asking question/making comment please avoid "it doesn't work" - please specify what you tried and what exactly did not go as *you* expected.

Comment: Always the same order .